# Jupyter Notebook with python

Tags: python, jupyter

Hi guys I just start with anaconda using jupyter notebook, but I have that issue when I execute, I need to understand end fix it

import pandas as pd

​

```
paris_listings = pd.read_csv('paris_airbnb.csv')
```

---

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b0392f32300c> in <module>
      2 import numpy as np
      3 
----> 4 paris_listings = pd.read_csv('paris_airbnb.csv')
      5 paris_listings

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    450 
    451     # Create the parser.
--> 452     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    453 
    454     if chunksize or iterator:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    934             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    935 
--> 936         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    937 
    938     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1166     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1167         if engine == "c":
-> 1168             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1169         else:
   1170             if engine == "python":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1996         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1997 
-> 1998         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1999         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   2000 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

**PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'paris_airbnb.csv'**
```

Comment: It seems that you do not have the rights to read the file

Comment: Try to execute Jupyter Notebook as admin

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the problem was my computer configuration. I changed computer and it work as admin.

```
import pandas as pd

paris_listings = pd.read_csv('paris_airbnb.csv')

print(paris_listings)

paris_listings.head()
```

host_response_rate  host_acceptance_rate  host_listings_count  latitude  \

0                  100%                   NaN                  1.0  48.83349
1                  100%                   NaN                  1.0  48.85100
2                  100%                   NaN                  2.0  48.85758
3                  100%                   NaN                  1.0  48.86528
4                   67%                   NaN                  3.0  48.85899